# Changing size of non-standard windows (Adobe CS6, MonoDevelop, etc)

Tags: objective-c, macos, accessibility, nswindow, nsrect

I'm working on an app that changes the size of windows and moves them around for the user using the Accessibility API. I'm having a problem with so called "custom" windows though:

Things with non-standard windows like Adobe CS6 just won't maximize or change position when I set the `NSAccessibilitySizeAttribute` value-- quite literally nothing happens. It works fine on all other windows though.

Is there any workaround to this? Anything I should look at in particular?

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves correctly, Adobe uses a lot of custom UI widgetry. You might look at Adobe's docs for scripting their apps, or contact Adobe.